# How I resolve warning message to import Flask from flask

Tags: python, flask, waitress

Command `From flask` not result (could not be resoulved)
I install the waitress server, but `from waitress` presents the same error.

[error presents in vscode IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St1cy.png)

I make a flask test with this simple code

```
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/route_name')
def home():
    return "Hello flask!"
```

I resolved flask import but now i have an error at connection localhost?\n

Error:

[WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qK3y.png)

I add `route name` in broken link and Tcharan, it worked!

Comment: Does the code run?  That just says the VSCode editor doesn't know where to find your modules.

Comment: Have you installed flask already?

Comment: @TimRoberts it does not run the code, as apparently it does not interpret the commands after `from`.

Comment: @JRiggles yes I have the flask installed, in the installation checks in my local machine it appears installed

Comment: You're gonna want to point your VScode to the same python version you've installed your dependencies for. Check this out: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#:~:text=your%20User%20Settings.-,To%20do%20so%2C%20open%20the%20Command%20Palette%20(Ctrl%2BShift,Settings%2C%20with%20the%20appropriate%20interpreter.

Comment: @A.J.Uppal ok, done. Now i have this error, on connecting server, see the image print in the updated question

Comment: That is simply a precautionary warning, which you should read.  It's not an error. You can clearly see that the server is running just fine.

Comment: @TimRoberts the link breaks when I access it, and the following message appears:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: The log shows that you tried to access `http://localhost:5000/`, but your server only implements `http://localhost:5000/route_name`.